# $p$-group with a normal subgroup of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am thinking about how to show that a finite $p$-group $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p$.

I thought of having $G$ act on the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$, but this seems to lead nowhere. Is there a simple way to prove this fact?

Comment: Yes, with Cauchy's theorem

Comment: It has a non-trivial centre.

Comment: Simplest way is to note that every subgroup of the center is necessarily normal, and that $p$-groups always have non-trivial center.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem gives us a subgroup of order $p$, but not that it is normal. $G$ has a nontrivial center, as it is a $p$-group. But why is this subgroup of order $p$ necessarily contained in the center?

Comment: Have you tried applying Cauchy's theorem to the center?

Comment: Ah, the center is nontrivial, normal in $G$, and is itself a $p$-group. By Cauchy's Theorem, it has a subgroup of order $p$. This subgroup is also normal in $G$.

Comment: @ponchan, why "This subgroup is also normal in $G$"?